# Finding mode in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the below query which returns me the mode which is the most repeated value in a data set

```
select top 1 TargetPriceRec as mode 
from PricingRecurring  
Group By TargetPriceRec order by Count(*) desc
```

I get the most repeated value from this but the issue is that if there is no repeated value I am still getting the highest value in the dataset. How can I get an empty value if there are no repeating values in the dataset and also if there are multiple repeating values I still get an empty value since there is no single mode.

Comment: Please show some sample data and expected results to illustrate what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I feel that the question, while basic, is quite clear. Not sure what's up with the close votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all the modes using:

```
select top (1) with ties TargetPriceRec as mode 
from PricingRecurring  
Group By TargetPriceRec
order by Count(*) desc;
```

For your desired results:

```
select (case when count(*) = 1 then max(TargetPriceRec) end) as mode
from (select top (1) with ties TargetPriceRec 
      from PricingRecurring  
      Group By TargetPriceRec
      order by Count(*) desc
     ) m
```

Comment: Thank you so much Gordon ..as always you rock.